# Push Notification content text not showing on Lollipop

Tags: android, push-notification, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Here is the code for showing push notification:

```
// receiverUid = unique uid for a receiver
// notificationUid = unique notification_uid
// receiverName, title, body are String variables.
NotificationCompat.Builder groupBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon_24)
                        .setColor(ColorUtils.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue_700))
                        .setGroupSummary(true)
                        .setGroup(receiverUid)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSubText(receiverName)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntentGroup);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon_24)
                        .setColor(ColorUtils.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue_700))
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntentNotification)
                        .setGroup(receiverUid)
                        .setSubText(receiverName)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// group notification is based on receiverUid, so the notifications are grouped under different receipients
        notificationManager.notify(receiverUid, 0, groupBuilder.build());
        notificationManager.notify(receiverUid + "_" + notificationUid, 0, builder.build());
```

This works fine on higher android versions, but the notification text is not shown for Lollipop versions. Here is screenshot on a Lollipop device:

[image: Notification text not showing on Lollipop]

I debugged and verified that the text is passed here. Please suggest. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group#set_a_group_summary) :

**Set a group summary**

> On Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher, the system automatically
> builds a summary for your group using snippets of text from each
> notification. The user can expand this notification to see each
> separate notification, as shown in figure 1. To support older
> versions, which cannot show a nested group of notifications, you must
> create an extra notification that acts as the summary. This appears as
> the only notification and the system hides all the others. So this
> summary should include a snippet from all the other notifications,
> which the user can tap to open your app

The text is not displayed because the groupBuilder is the one that is displayed and it does not contain any text so for the lesser version of API 27 add your text to the groupBuilder or create a style to summarize the contents of the other notification for example :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder groupBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon_24)
                        .setColor(ColorUtils.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue_700))
                        .setGroupSummary(true)
                        .setGroup(receiverUid)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSubText(receiverName)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntentGroup)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                                 .addLine("Alex Faarborg  Check this out")
                                 .setBigContentTitle("2 new messages")
                                 .setSummaryText("janedoe@example.com"));
```

**Update :**
implement the notification count and the messages summary in the Style

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int notificationCount = 0;
    private NotificationCompat.InboxStyle style;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // also you can Save the Notification count on the sharePreference
        // for simulate the notification with multiple message
        String[][] person = {{"Bill", "Jones"}, {"Janet", "Kline"}, {"George", "Bailey"},
                {"Ellan", "Sanches"}, {"Tom", "Nguyen"}, {"William", "Walters"}, {"Author", "James"},
                {"Henry", "Daniels"}, {"Mike", "Franklin"}, {"Julie", "Andrews"}};

        // i have just testing with the TimeDownCount to add notifications every 20 seconds
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 10) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // get random person from the array person 
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomInt = random.nextInt(person.length - 1);
                // show notification
                showNotification(person[randomInt][0] + " " + person[randomInt][1]);
                if (notificationCount < 10) {
                    this.start();
                }
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
        style = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    }


    private void showNotification(String message) {
        notificationCount++;
        
        style.addLine(message); // add person to the style 
        style.setBigContentTitle(notificationCount + " new messages"); // show Notification count in the Title

        NotificationCompat.Builder groupBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_mic_24)
                        .setColor(Color.BLUE)
                        .setGroupSummary(true)
                        .setGroup("receiverUid")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setStyle(style)
                        .setSubText("Your Action");

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_mic_24)
                        .setColor(Color.BLUE)
                        .setContentTitle("title")
                        .setContentText("body")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setGroup("receiverUid")
                        .setSubText("receiverName")
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify("receiverUid", 0, groupBuilder.build());
        notificationManager.notify("receiverUid" + "_" + "notificationUid", 0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

overview of how the code works :

[image]

Comment: So, three things here:
1. do I need to save the incoming notifications and create/update group summary each time?
2. are the individual notifications not accessible separately on api<24 as they are in api >=24?
3. Is then creating a separate notification without grouping better for api<24 since we loose the ability to open each notification separately via potentially different deeplinks? @shay-kin

Comment: OK I'll answer your second question first, as long as you add `.setGroupSummary (true)` the system displays a single notification and hides the others from the same group so you cannot access the notification separately, and for the third one imagine that we have 5 or more notifications I see it not very paratic to display them all, but it remains my opinion, and as you said we lose the accessibility of the click. and lastly display a notification which summarizes all the others of the same group and when the user clicks on it you can direct it to a list which displays all the details

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have one more doubt regarding 1st question... Imagine notifications arriving every hour and the user not opening them for a few hours.. How do I summarise in this case? Do I store every incoming notification in a local database? @shay-kin

Comment: Yes if you can do it but note that you cannot display all the messages in style due to the limited size of the notification. except you can display the recent notifcation plus the number of new incoming notifications, like the example of the offcial documentation, and when the user clicks on your notification you must display all the data that you have saved in the local database

Comment: Got it.. Makes sense..Can I somehow access how many/what notifications are currently showing in the android phone's notification panel from my app? - This is needed to summarise only the notifications being displayed in the notification panel..I may not be able to keep track of what's showing currently as people do swipe clear notifications..

Comment: hi please check my answer i updated it. for the number of notification i have not found a way to count them but you can do it with a simple counter. let me know if it will help you